# How to filter the latest 7 days to export the data from Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'd like to export the table from 'log' table just for the latest 7 days which is mapped as 'DATE' column. How can I proceed the next?

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE (MAX(DATE))
```

MAX function is not applied on WHERE clause.

Comment: you can try like this --> `SELECT * FROM log WHERE date > CURRENT_DATE - 7`

Comment: @Jaytiger Thanks for your comment! The thing is, this dataset is injected once on every week, which means we need to avoid the function CURRENT_DATE. Do you have any idea?

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM log WHERE date > (SELECT MAX(date) FROM log) - 7` ?

Comment: @Jaytiger Cannot query over table 'log' without a filter over column(s) 'DATE' that can be used for partition elimination

I think there must be OVER/PARTITION but I'm confused how to apply.

Comment: Then try `(SELECT MAX(date) FROM log WHERE date IS NOT NULL)` instead.  What I understood is that you want to query data from 7 days ago before `MAX(date)`.